# Q/A of a deleted user showed up in the review queue

Tags: bug

I was clearing the review queue (first answers) and besides it being larger than usual, I soon noticed about half of it was related to questions or answers of a (newly?) deleted user — user13395.

Most were already upvoted or commented on ([example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49015/possible-solution-for-dangling-nodes)), but since it has been only two weeks, maybe they really are candidates for review. It does look like they entered the queue just due to the user being deleted though (appearing as a newcomer). I've found a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149124/first-post-review-for-deleted-user) on the main meta site, but it only handles the usefulness of this behaviour, not if the site's queuing algorithms is flawed in this case. Can anyone clear this up?